# GXT - 3: HTML code is displayed rather than the image

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

Find the image for the problem:

I am trying to create a column which displays multiple images which contains clickable events. But instead of image, I am getting the HTML code.

[image]

The column config I have written is as follows:

```
    actionsCol = new ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,String>(new ValueProvider<SensorTreeModel, String>() {
          com.sencha.project.client.Resources resources = GWT.create(com.sencha.project.client.Resources.class);
            @Override
            public String getValue(SensorTreeModel String) {
                //ImageResource image = resources.add();
                FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();

                ImageResource add = com.sencha.project.client.Resources.INSTANCES.add();
                Image add1 = new  Image(add);
                flowPanel.add(add1);
              //return add1;
              return flowPanel.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(SensorTreeModel object, String value) {
              if (object.getIsLeaf()) {

              }
            }

            @Override
            public String getPath() {
              return "actions";
            }
          });
      actionsCol.setHeader("");
```

Comment: sorry to forget setCell I had add it to answer. I hope it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ColumnConfig`<M,N>`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/ColumnConfig.html) and [ValueProvider`<T,V>`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/core/client/ValueProvider.html), N and V are the same and type of columns content. So on your example you are returning String as value. If you return ImageResource, column will show Image.

I hope it helps.

```
  actionsCol = new ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,ImageResource>(new ValueProvider<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>() {
             com.sencha.project.client.Resources resources = GWT.create(com.sencha.project.client.Resources.class);
             @Override
             public ImageResource getValue(SensorTreeModel String) {

                  ImageResource add = com.sencha.project.client.Resources.INSTANCES.add();
                  return add;
                }

                @Override
                public void setValue(SensorTreeModel object, ImageResource value) {
                  if (object.getIsLeaf()) {

                  }
                }

                @Override
                public String getPath() {
                  return "actions";
                }
      });
 actionsCol.setHeader("");
actionsCol.setCell(new ImageResourceCell());
```

Comment: Additionally, you'll need to have a cell that knows how to render this! (and what is that FlowPanel doing, besides being expensive to create but unused?)

Comment: @ColinAlworth Yes, FlowPanel is also unnecesary :) I only change required parts of deepak's code

Comment: Still need a custom cell, or it is going to just `.toString()` the ImageResource, which won't render the image.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thanks for your attention. setCell method added with parameter com.google.gwt.cell.client.ImageResourceCell

Comment: @YusufK. It works, But what if I want to add multiple images and each image needs a click handler? I have an idea about using CompositeCell. So, any suggestions? I initially used FlowPanel to add multiple images. But that doesn't work. :(

Comment: @deepaknalore Using CompositeCell is the solution for clickable images on same column.

Comment: @YusufK.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127646/gxt-3-columnconfig-setcell-not-working-for-compositecell
Can you please look into this code?

Comment: @deepaknalore if this(also any) answer is satisfied your question, please do not forget accept and upvote it.