# GXT 3 - ColumnConfig.setCell() not working for CompositeCell

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to create a column with multiple images in a single grid cell. 
The following is the column config

```
 private ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,ImageResource> actionsCol;
 actionsCol = new ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,ImageResource>(new ValueProvider<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>() {
          com.sencha.project.client.Resources resources = GWT.create(com.sencha.project.client.Resources.class);
            @Override
            public ImageResource getValue(SensorTreeModel object) {

                ImageResource add = com.sencha.project.client.Resources.INSTANCES.add();
                return add;
           }

            @Override
            public void setValue(SensorTreeModel object, ImageResource value) {
              if (object.getIsLeaf()) {

              }
            }

            @Override
            public String getPath() {
              return "actions";
            }
          });
      actionsCol.setHeader("");
      //This is where an error occurs      
     actionsCol.setCell(compositeCell);
```

Each of my image cell looks like below:

```
public class ImageCell implements HasCell<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>{
private ImageResourceCell imageCell = new ImageResourceCell();
@Override
public Cell<ImageResource> getCell() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageCell;
}

@Override
public FieldUpdater<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource> getFieldUpdater() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new FieldUpdater<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>() {
          @Override
          public void update(int index, SensorTreeModel object, ImageResource value) {
             //object.setLast(ImageResource(value));
          }         
        };
}

@Override
public ImageResource getValue(SensorTreeModel object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return com.sencha.project.client.Resources.INSTANCES.add();
}
```

}

The composite cell looks like below:

```
 List<HasCell<SensorTreeModel, ?>> cells= new ArrayList<HasCell<SensorTreeModel,?>>();
      cells.add(new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell());
      cells.add(new com.sencha.project.client.ImageCell());

      CompositeCell<SensorTreeModel> compositeCell = new CompositeCell<SensorTreeModel>(cells);
```

So, what I am trying to do is create a number of images in a grid cell. I initially create an ImageCell which returns an image. Now, I add number of these cells onto the composite cell. Later I reference this composite cell from the setCell function in actionsCol (column config).

Comment: What is specifically "not working"? Are the images you are passing in not rendering? Are the cells not correctly drawing two `<img>` tags in each grid cell? There are a lot of things that are not shared here that could be wrong and aren't mentioned, like the grid not having data, the grid not being sized, etc.

Comment: The "setCell" function wasn't working. If you look at the first set of code, I have mentioned in the comment where the error is.

Comment: `ColumnConfig.setCell(...)` does nothing except assign the field, it wouldn't even cause an error if the cell was null - what is the error message or stack trace?

Comment: @ColinAlworth You have misunderstood me. I can't send compositeCell as an argument for ColumnConfig.setCell(). I can't even compile my code.

Comment: Okay, what is the error that you get when you compile? None of us here are compilers, and you only have shared small snippets of your class, so we need all the data you have to be able to help.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thanks for your help. I figured out that I could add the cell by changing:
private ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,ImageResource> actionsCol;
to:
private ColumnConfig<SensorTreeModel,SensorTreeModel> actionsCol;
Any explanation for this?